# Accessing "Env variables" at public folder of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How we can access env variable at public(file.js)?

I have tried with ruby tags but it didn't worked

app > public > custom.js

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ENV["server_url"]+'/home/example', 
     data: {zip_to: response.postal},
     dataType: 'script'
    })
```

i have also tried but it was of no use

```
url: <%= ENV["server_url"]%>+'/home/example',
```

Comment: Did you try `url: "<%= ENV['server_url'] %>/home/example"`?

Comment: yeah...! but it isn't working that way.
I have also tried with "#{ENV['server_url']}" but did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Files from `public` are served to client "as is" without any preprocessing.

Easiest way to pass a variable to js is to add values to your html in some way (data attributes of body tag or set on `window` via inline scripts, also there's a gem for that - [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon))

But if there's no html and you want js to actually contain these values - you can render js like any other text: create corresponding route/controller and template `action_name.js.erb`, `<%= %>`-tags will work there.